# Why do I want this class to extend an interface, and what is the right design pattern for this?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose I have an interface `Employee` and there are many classes that implement it, such as `Bob`, `Joe`, and `Mary`, none of which may be changed.

```
public interface Employee{
  public void work()
}

public class Mary implements Employee{
  public void work(){
    //Mary's implementation of work
  }
}
```

I must make a `Manager` class that is a wrapper for an `Employee` object. So the constructor for `Manager` takes an object of type `Employee`

```
Public class Manager{
private Employee employee;

  public Manager(Employee employee){
     this.employee = employee;
  }

  public void work(){
    this.employee.work()
  }

  public void manage(){
     //my implementation of manage
  }


}
```

When a `Manager` object is instantiated, it should have all the methods of the underlying `Employee` plus a few extra. Most of the methods of the underlying `Employee` object will not be overridden (see `work`), and thus I think I should be extending `Employee`. But a class cannot extend an interface. Currently, I am working on declaring each of the `Employee` methods within the `Manager` class and having them simply call the corresponding `Employee` method. But that seems like unnecessary boilerplate and like it will break if the Employee interface ever changes.

Since extending an interface is not allowed, What is the correct design pattern for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Since when can you not extend an interface? In fact a subinterface uses the `extends` keyword when extending a superinterface in Java.

Comment: Snowman: An interface can extend an interface, but a class cannot extend an interface. I could make a `ManagerInterface extends Employee` but then my `Manager implements ManagerInterface` would still have to declare an implementation for every method of Employee and of ManagerInterface, leaving me where I started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing it is basically the usual way of doing this in a static language.  You should probably declare your `Manager` to implement `Employee`, but other than that there really isn't a better way of achieving the result you want.

In some dynamically-typed languages (e.g. Ruby or Smalltalk) there is another alternative: you can implement a method that gets called if your object is sent an unrecognised message (i.e. it's called with a method it doesn't know about), and you can then forward that message to the target object.  Java has no way of doing this.

Comment: if Manager implements Employee, what happens when you accidentally pass an already  Manager Employee as a parameter to a new Manager?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need inheritance in this case, you need composition:

```
public interface Manager {
    void manage();
}

public class Mary implements Employee, Manager{
    public void work(){
        //Mary's implementation of work
    }

    public void manage(){
        //manage
    }
}
```

Java allows classes to implement multiple interfaces, and is a good guideline: [Why should I prefer composition over inheritance?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

If you literally cannot change the `Mary` class, than you should do a wrapper object like you have, which would act as an Adapter for the Employee class instances.

I don't think you need to extend the Employee interface, since you did not indicate that it will need a `work()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You said *I must make a Manager class that is a **wrapper** for an Employee object* 
Purpose of the wrapper exactly what you described, it wrap some other behavior under own methods.

I think your `Manager` class need to implement `Employee` interface.

```
Public class Manager implements Employee
{
    private Employee employee;

    public Manager(Employee employee)
    {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public void work()
    {
        this.employee.work();
    }

    public void manage()
    {
        //my implementation of manage
    }
}
```

In this case `Manager` class wrap behavior of `Employee` interface and extend it with own manager behavior.