# OOP and class that inherit from many classes

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, inheritance

In OOP, is it possible to have a class that inherits from multiple other classes? And if yes, how is this situation called?

For example, suppose I have the following classes:

```
Eye
Nose
Mouth
Eyebrow
Ear
Hair
Skin
```

Now I want to have a class called `Face` which should inherit or depend on all these classes to make a `Face` object. In other words I want to assemble many classes into one class.

Comment: I don't think you want inheritance in your example but rather ***composition***. `Face` should have members `Eye`, `Nose`, etc. but not actually implement them.

Comment: The term is "how to use inheritance wrong" ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I prefer composition over inheritance?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Comment: The "is it possible" question is easily answered with "it depends if the language allows it". It being a good idea is a completely different pair of shoes. For your example in fact, it would be a terrible idea, as you probably want `Face` to be a container for all the other things, not a subclass.

Comment: Your face is not an eye. It is not a nose, or a mouth, or an eyebrow and so on. It has usually two eyes, sometimes fewer. It has one nose, sometimes fewer and so on. You absolutely 100% do NOT want to inherit from Eye, Nose and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you start to learn on OOP, one of the first thing that you need to learn is to prefer **[composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)**.

In your example, a face ***has*** eyes, mouth, ears, .... When an object of a class assembles objects from other classes in that way, it is called ***[composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)***. This is what you need.

This being said, and to satisfy your curiosity about [***inheritance***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)):

- inheritance is a very special relationship that should mean ***is-a***:  a `Dog` is-an `Animal`, so it may inherit from it.
- most OOP languages allow [multilevel inheritance](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/multilevel-inheritance-in-java-with-example/), where one class inherits from another class with inherits from a third: a `GermanShepherd` inherits from `Dog` which inherits from `Animal`.
- some OOP languages allow [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) where one class can inherit from several others (example:  a `Dog` could inherit from `Pet` and have a method `showAffection()`, and at the same time inherit from `Animal` and have a method `findFood()`.
- many OOP languages don't provide multiple inheritance, but propose the concept of [interface](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/interfaces.html) to achieve similar effects.  (The main difference is that the class has to implement itself the behaviors promised by its multiple interfaces.)

Comment: Very nice job after your edit - I wouldn't have bothered with my answer.

Comment: You might mention mixin inheritance. Mixin inheritance subsumes almost all classical forms of inheritance: Simula-style class-based inheritance (as in Smalltalk, Objective-C, C++, PHP, Python, Ruby, …), Beta-style prefixing (where superclass methods call the subclass implementation instead of subclasses calling `super`), and multiple inheritance with linearization (e.g. CLOS, Dylan, Python).

Answer (score 3):

You want Composition, not Inheritance,  Here's a good overview of [Inheritance vs Composition.](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php)

To elaborate, Inheritance represents a possible "is a" relationship.  For example, if you have a Letter class, the particular letter M "is-a" letter.  If you have a Vehicle class, "Audi A4" is a Car, which could be a subclass of vehicle.  (though you might not want inheritance here either, YMMV)

Composition represents a "has a" relationship.  My garage is not a Car, but it "has a" car.  "Audi" is not a letter, but is has a (bunch of) letters.

In your example, nobody would say that the face "is an" eye.  But it "has" 0, 1, or 2 eyes.

Modern "best practice" is to favor composition over inheritance, so, when it doubt, don't subclass.

Answer (score 0):

[This is in addition to @Christophe's answer.]

> In OOP, is it possible to have a class inherits from another multiple classes? and if it is true, what is the term of this situation?

The term for what's proposed in the original question is [*multiple inheritance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).  For the purposes of this conversation, inheritance can be divided into two flavors: *implementation inheritance* and *interface inheritance*.  Hardly any OO languages support multiple implementation inheritance, because rarely can it be implemented well.  Many OO languages support single implementation inheritance and multiple interface inheritance.